# How can I prove MDI child auto resize?

Tags: vb.net

This is my problem in VB
I use Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express
and this is my MDI Child Form I designed

[image]

But when I run my project(start debugging)
and call any MDI Child Form 
it's resized

[image]

How can I prove this problem?

Comment: Make it bigger or set the Anchor properties correctly.  Anchoring the text boxes to the right and the labels to the left is your core problem here.  If you don't want the overlap then it all has to anchor to the left.